# Простейший socket-client: что-то не работает.

Tags: java, сокет

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("docs.oracle.com", 8080);
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    boolean autoflush = true;
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), autoflush);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));  
    boolean loop = true;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(8096);
    while (loop) {
        if (in.ready()) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i != -1)
            {
                i = in.read();
                sb.append((char) i);
            }
            loop = false;
        }
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
    } 
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    socket.close();
```

Делаю по книге простейший сокет-клиент. Хочу через него присоединиться к сайту и скачать страницу. Не получается - говорит

> java.net.ConnectException: Operation
> timed out

Что не так? Или я что-то не так понял в сокетах?

Comment: @KutaBeach, есть такая полезная утилтка - **ncat**. 

Советую сначала соединяться ей, смотреть что получаете, а потом отлаживать свою программу.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы telnet-ом )

Comment: Спасибо, я совсем не разбираюсь в сетях, а чем это лучше ping?

Comment: грубо говоря, пинг позволяет узнать в сети ли хост с указанным адресом (при том не всегда). netcat позволяет подключиться к конкретному порту на хосте и вручную погонять данные туда-сюда.

Если тема вам интересна - рекомендую почитать [Протоколы TCP/IP. Практическое руководство](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1354276/).

Comment: Эммм..., а что нельзя было сначала потестить на `localhost`, подняв на нем Tomcat? Многие вопросы сразу бы отпали.

Comment: ну быстрее-то на внешнем, и поднимать ничего не надо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно со времен написания книги хост `docs.oracle.com` перестал прослушивать порт `8080`. О чем вам и говорится в исключении: вы пытались подключиться, но за выделенный интервал времени сервер не ответил.

Попробуйте `80`й порт, а не `8080`.

Comment: Как все быстро меняется! Спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

[[@KutaBeach](/users/2384/kutabeach)](/users/2384/kutabeach), такая Ваша прграмма работать не будет. Вы соединяетесь с web-сервером, он хочет "общаться" по протоколу http.

Перед тем, как читать, Вы должны что-то передать ему. Нормально, например:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
HOST: docs.oracle.com
```

(закончить надо пустой строкой, здесь не вводится). Строки завершаются парой символов \r\n.

На такой запрос Вы получите осмысленный ответ. Признаком конца данных (для этого запроса) будет чтение пустой строки.

Можете также отправить любую ерунду, но обязательно завершая передачей пустой строки.

```
xaxa

--- выше пустая строка ---
```

Тоже получите ответ, в конце сервер закроет соединение.

Вообще читайте RFC2616.